# Quickblox push notification for chat not working in ios

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push, quickblox

I am using quickblox for my chatting app. But push notification is not working. I have uploaded ck.pem on admin panel. It shows error log. And that error is : **"Certificate errors:
2015-10-23 08:50:25 UTC: Connection reset by APNS: Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 error"** .. And the same ck.pem i am using on my server. its working fine. Dont know why its not working in chat.
Kindly Plz help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to upload the same certificate from another PC. And it worked.!! Weird. :/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are uploading correct certificate. Try to export it one more time in Keychain with your private key and upload it to admin panel.

Comment: I export 2 items from keychain certi and prv key and save it as .p12. When I upload p12 certi in admin panel it shows - Error Bad certificate file (P12 or PEM required) . And when i upload .pem then it shows error which i have mentioned in my question.